# Group nodes based on authors (the current user, and the rest of users)

Tags: views

I know how to group fields based on UID using Views.
but Id like to know how I am able to do that only into two groups:

1. The nodes that I created myself
2. The nodes that the rest of the users have created

is this possible to do so in ONE view?